# Applying Theme Colors From Pivot Table to Adjacent Cells

Tags: excel, vba, colors, themes, pivot-table

I am having a problem in [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) where I want to copy the color of one cell to the next but when it copies, the color is always white or 'no fill.'
The following code sample is the problem area:

```
'If the status cell('E') is empty (is not a table header)
        If rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then

           'Apply the color of 'C' column to the cells in the status('E') and note('F') column
            rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ThemeColor = rngCell.Interior.ThemeColor
            rngCell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.ThemeColor = rngCell.Interior.ThemeColor
        End If
```

I believe the problem is that I am trying to copy the color of a cell that is in a pivot table to a cell that isn't in the pivot table. This is why I am using '.ThemeColor;' the color is set to "Pivot Style Medium 2" and that color is not available using .ColorIndex.

I have tried using .ColorIndex, .Color, .ThemeColor but all attempts give the same result

The following code sample is the whole code to give context but the problem lays in the last else statement.

```
'Initialize variables to save cell ranges
Dim rngTables As range
Dim rngClick As range
Dim rngCell As range

'Set the range of cells to be checked
'We want to check the description fields to check if there is description text
'Cells with descriptions are the parameters being tested
Set rngTables = range("C4:C200")

'Loop through the cells in rngTables using rngCell to check each cell individually
For Each rngCell In rngTables

    'Add cells to rngClick if they are NOT Blank
    If Not rngCell.Value = "" And Not rngCell.Value = "Description" Then
        If Not rngClick Is Nothing Then

            'Add the 2nd, 3rd, 4th... Cell to our new range, rng2
            'This is the most common outcome so place it first in the IF test (faster coding)
            Set rngClick = Union(rngClick, rngCell.Offset(0, 2))
        Else

            'The first valid cell becomes rngClick
            Set rngClick = rngCell.Offset(0, 2)
        End If
    Else

        'If the status cell('E') is empty (is not a table header)
        If rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then

           'Apply the color of 'C' column to the cells in the status('E') and note('F') column
            rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ThemeColor = rngCell.Interior.ThemeColor
            rngCell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.ThemeColor = rngCell.Interior.ThemeColor
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by using the **DisplayFormat.Interior.Color** which extracts theme colors from a pivot table.

```
If rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then

           'Apply the color of 'C' column to the cells in the status('E') and note('F') column
            rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Color = rngCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
            rngCell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = rngCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        End If
```